# How to transform a dataset into a presence/absence matrix?

Tags: r, excel, excel-formula, dataset, data-transform

My dataset follows this model:

| Species | Year |
| --- | --- |
| Species_1 | 2000 |
| Species_1, Species_2 | 2003 |
| Species_2, Species_3 | 2005 |

I would like to change my final dataframe something like this:

|  | Species_1 | Species_2 | Species_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2003 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2005 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

How can I transform the first dataset to the second with *Excel* or *R*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tidy solution:

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat <- data.frame(
  species = c("species_1", "species_1, species_2", "species_2, species_3"), 
  year = c(2000, 2003, 2005)
)
library(stringr)
dat %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(species = list(str_split(species, ",")[[1]])) %>% 
  unnest(species) %>% 
  mutate(species = trimws(species), 
         value=1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="species", values_fill = 0)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>    year species_1 species_2 species_3
#>   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1  2000         1         0         0
#> 2  2003         1         1         0
#> 3  2005         0         1         1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>